# What's the relation between $\limsup$ and $\inf\sup$?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I've found in my book that:
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \ x_{n} = \sup\{\inf\{x_{k}:k\geq n \}:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \ x_{n} = \inf\{\sup\{x_{k}:k\geq n \}:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

But I don't understand why. According to my book the definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ is the following:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \ s_{n} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sup  \{s_{n}:n > N \} $$

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \ s_{n} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \inf  \{s_{n}:n > N \} $$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing that two definitions of $\limsup$ are equivalent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515652/showing-that-two-definitions-of-limsup-are-equivalent)

Comment: @skyking, this does not seem to be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @lhf I was a little quick there, it's only related...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $X_n=\{x_{k}:k\geq n \}$. Then $X_{n+1} \subseteq X_n$ and therefore:
$$
\inf X_n \le \inf X_{n+1}
\le
\sup X_{n+1} \le \sup X_n
$$
This implies:

- $a_n=\sup X_n$ is a decreasing sequence and so $\lim_n a_n = \inf_n a_n$.
- $b_n=\inf X_n$ is an increasing sequence and so $\lim_n b_n = \sup_n b_n$.

Comment: Maybe it's trivial but how do you know that $b_{n}$ is an increasing sequence?

Comment: @JellyBelly Because of $\{x_n \mid k\geq n+1\} \subseteq \{x_n \mid k\geq n\}$, the $\inf$ of the first set cannot be smaller than the $\inf$ of the latter set, which is to say $b_{n+1} \not<b_n$ for all $n$.