# Prove that $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sup{\{a_n: n \ge N\}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

If $\{a_{n}\}$ is a sequence of real numbers, prove that $\displaystyle\limsup_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = \displaystyle\lim_{N \to \infty} \sup{\{a_n: n \ge N\}}$.

It is sort of intuitively clear, since $\sup_{n > 1}{a_{n}}$, $\sup_{n > 2}{a_{n}}$ ... is nonincreasing sequence and for any N, we have that $\sup_{n\ge N} a_n \le \sup_{n\ge 1}a_n$. So eventually $\sup_{n\ge N} a_n$ should be equal to $\displaystyle\limsup_{n \to \infty}{a_n}$, but how to prove it formally?
By the definition of limsup from Rudin, limsup is a supremum of a set of subsequential limits, but it does no seem to help here.

Comment: Several posts discussing equivalence of various definitions of limit superior can be found on this site. Some of them are [listed here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838490/questions-on-limit-superiors/838595#838595).

Comment: In particular, these questions seems to be closely related: [Showing that two definitions of $\limsup$ are equivalent](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1515652) and [How to prove that the limsup of a sequence is equal to its greatest subsequential limit?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100742)

Answer (score 1):

I try to give an answer which is independent on the various definitions of $\limsup a_n$, basing on the two following elementary lemmas.

**Lemma 1**. Let $\langle a_n \rangle = \{ a_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a (not necessarily strictly) monotonically decreasing succession of extended real numbers (i.e. $a_n\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}= \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty, -\infty\}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$). Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \inf\langle a_n \rangle
$$
**Proof**. The case $\inf\langle a_n \rangle=\infty$ is trivial. If $\inf\langle a_n \rangle\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$, from the definition of *infimum* of a set of real numbers we have that, for any given real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $m$ 
$$
\begin{cases}
      a_m < -\varepsilon & \text{if }  \inf\langle a_n \rangle =-\infty,\\
      0 \leq a_m - \inf\langle a_n \rangle < \varepsilon & \text{if } \inf\langle a_n \rangle \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{cases}
$$
But since $\langle a_n \rangle$ is monotonically decreasing, for every natural $n\geq m$ 
$$
\begin{cases}
      a_n < -\varepsilon & \text{if }  \inf\langle a_n \rangle =-\infty,\\
      0 \leq a_n - \inf\langle a_n \rangle < \varepsilon & \text{if } \inf\langle a_n \rangle \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n = \inf\langle a_n \rangle.\quad\blacksquare
$$

**Lemma 2**. Let $\langle a_n \rangle = \{ a_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a (not necessarily strictly) monotonically decreasing succession of extended real numbers, and let $\langle a_n \rangle_{n\geq{N}} = \{ a_n : n\geq N, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a subsequence obtained from $\langle a_n \rangle$ by omitting its first $N$ terms. Then
$$
\inf\langle a_n \rangle = \inf\langle a_n \rangle_{n\geq{N}}
$$
**Proof**. It is a trivial consequence of the definition of *infimum* of a set of real numbers and of *monotone sequence* of real numbers. $\blacksquare$

Put $A_n = \sup \{ a_m : m\geq n\}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$: now $\langle A_n \rangle$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence of extended real numbers, as noted by user0347284: therefore, by applying to it the two preceding lemmas one gets the sought for proof:
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = \inf\langle A_n \rangle = \inf\langle A_n \rangle_{n\geq{N}} = \lim_{N \to \infty} A_N = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sup \{ a_n : n\geq N\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You could try to construct a subsequence with $$a_{k_n}\ge\sup_{m>n}a_m-2^{-n}.$$

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. How can it help me?

Comment: If successful, you get a sub-sequence that converges to $\lim_n\sup_{m>n}a_n$.