# $\limsup a_n=-\infty$ if $\{a_n\}$ does not have a subsequence which is bounded below

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, proof-writing, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to prove the second part of the following question stated as

1. If $\{a_n\}$ has a subsequence which is bounded below by $\alpha$ then $\limsup a_n\geq \alpha$.
2. If $\{a_n\}$ does not have a subsequence which is bounded below, then $\limsup a_n=-\infty$.

Here is my solution for the first question;

> Let $\{a_{{n}_{k}}\}\subset\{a_n\}$ be bounded below by $\alpha$. Then, $\exists\;\alpha\in \Bbb{R}:\alpha\leq \{a_{{n}_{k}}\},\;k\geq1$
>   $$\implies \alpha\leq a_{{n}_{k}}\leq \sup_{j \ge n_k}\{a_{j}\},\forall\;k\geq1$$
>   $$\implies \alpha\leq\lim_{k\to \infty} \sup_{j \ge n_k}\{a_{j}\}\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\sup\{a_{{n}}\}$$
>   $$\implies \alpha\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\sup\{a_{{n}}\}$$

Please, can anyone help me with the second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n$ has no subsequence which is bounded below, then $$\forall\alpha\in\mathbf R\space \forall N \space \exists n > N(a_n<\alpha)
$$ for if not, the sequence $a_N,a_{N+1},\dots$ would be bounded below by $\alpha$.  So for every $\alpha$ we can construct a subsequence whose sup is less than $\alpha$, and from there you should have plain sailing.

Comment: @ saulspatz: I negated it just like you did, before now, but couldn't continue. Could you please help complete it?

Comment: @Mike Do you know that the lim sup is the [sup of the set of subsequential limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100742/how-to-prove-that-the-limsup-of-a-sequence-is-equal-to-its-greatest-subsequentia)?